# Offsetting Workaround in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, accounting

I am trying to automate posting accounting journal entries to a ledger, and am struggling with offsetting after I add new rows. My workbook has two sheets, Journal and Ledger, and my goal is to read each journal entry and add the entry to the correct T-account in the ledger by adding a new row. Most of the the copying entries works, but the macro runs into problems once the offsetting changes. I was considering using `.Find` as a better option since different T-accounts need different offsetting values depending one how many previous accounts are above them. How can I solve this offsetting row problem?

Here is a link to the [Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-S_Oyu8bMqyM0RJUWFTeFY5VlE/view?usp=sharing), and below is my code in VBA.

```
Sub RowInsert()

Dim offset As Integer
offset = 0

Dim counter As Integer
For counter = 0 To 1

Dim account As String
account = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 2)


Dim a As Double

If Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 2) = "Cash" Then
Worksheets("Ledger").Rows(4 + offset).Insert Shift:=xlDown

offset = offset + 1

Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(6 + offset, 1).Value = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 1).Value

    If Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 3).Value = Null Then
    Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(6 + offset, 3).Value = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 4).Value
    Else
    Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(6 + offset, 2).Value = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 3).Value
    End If

ElseIf Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 2) = "Equipment" Then
Worksheets("Ledger").Rows(8 + offset).Insert Shift:=xlDown

offset = offset + 1

Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(6 + offset, 1).Value = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 1).Value

    If Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 3).Value = Null Then
    Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(6 + offset, 3).Value = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 4).Value
    Else
    Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(6 + offset, 2).Value = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 3).Value
    End If

End If
Next counter
End Sub
```

EDIT. If I were to pursue the `Range.Find` solution, how can I access this Range/cell result? Right now I get "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set".

```
Sub RowInsert()

Dim counter As Integer
For counter = 0 To 1

Dim account As String
account = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 2)


Dim a As Double

If Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 2) = "Cash" Then

    Dim entries As Integer
    entries = 0
    Dim Header As Range
    Dim row As Long

    With Worksheets("Ledger").Range("a1:a100")

        Set Header = .Find("Cash")
        ` Error here when try to use the Range Header
        row = Header.row + entries

        Rows(row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Cells(row, 1) = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 1).Value

    End With

End If
Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Find` sounds like a good idea if you need to have the accounts beneath each other. Look into the `.End(xlDown)` method. It will help you find the last row of an account once you have found the first row.

Comment: How would I prevent `.End(xlDown)` from continuing on to the next account below it?

Comment: I would assume that you have at least one empty row between accounts. `.End(xlDown)` stops there (if applied to a non-empty cell) which is why it shouldn't be used to find the very last row in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your edited question:

The error you receive is because `.Find` didn't find anything and returned `Nothing`. Trying to access properties of `Nothing` will give the "Object variable or With block variable not set" error.

`.Find` doesn't handle merged cells that well. The easy solution in your case is to extend the search range so it includes the whole merged cell.

```
Dim Header As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Ledger").Columns("A:C")

    Set Header = .Find("Cash")
    lastRow = Header.Row + entries
    'I would prefer something like
    'lastRow = Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(Header.Row, "B").End(xlDown).Row (not tested)

    Rows(lastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(lastRow, 1) = Worksheets("Journal").Cells(counter + 2, 1).Value
End With
```

I changed the name of the row variable so there's no confusion between the property `Row` and your variable `row`. You can see that the VBE is already confused as it's setting the property to lower case.